# Should I define `foreign key Id` property in addition to the corresponding `navigation property`?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I found these entities in one of Microsoft tutorials:

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Do I really need to define `StudentId` property?

How the case will differ in case of different types of relationshipts? for example `one-one` and `one-many`?

## UPDATE:

In this link http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships we can see that in One-Many and Many-Many, they did not define the Id foreign key property, but in One-One, they did. Why is that?

Comment: It depends on the relation you're trying to model. The StudentId is the FK for Enrollment to match a Student. When you say it worked -- what worked? Did the relationship work both ways? Isn't there also a Course table and Enrollment is the relation table for Student-Course?

Comment: @Jasen I edited the question a little bit, could you explain for the both mentioned relationships? I am a little bit confused about that. Ok yes there were Courses relationship, but I think it does not matter in my question right? I deleted it to keep everything simple.

Comment: I guess yes, because EF Core use that column according to ef core naming convention

Comment: @H.Herzl, Thank you, but actually I need a concrete answer, because I do not find it in all tutorials I found, and should it be on both sides of the relationship, or only one side?

Comment: About to add definition for StudentId, remember ef needs a property to generate the join otherwise ef cannot generate join for query. If you don't apply any mapping (fluent api or data annotation) you must to follow the convention, otherwise you can change the name for column.

Comment: I'm thinking in shadow properties, you can check into that...

Comment: I added a new link in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a partial answer for my question in this page:

http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions

> Foreign Key Shadow Properties:
>   If you choose not to explicitly include a foreign key property in the dependant end of the relationship, EF Core will create a shadow property using the pattern Id.

But I still do not know if this is the case in all types of relationships.

I hope that helps some one.

## UPDATE

Ok now I found exactly what I wanted to know and understand, please take a look on these links which include the difference conventions of creating the Models (entities):

http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship

http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-one-relationship

Comment: Still it is not clear when to use Shadow Property or explicit definition of the relationships' keys.